# Need ArrayList printed without "Brackets"

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jsp-tags

Hello everyone I have an arraylist showing up as `[MCA, MCB, COMM, DMISA]` on the jsp.

Im calling it on the jsp:

```
<td>${bean.CodesNames}</td>
```

In the bean the getter is:

```
public void setCodesNames(ArrayList<String> CodesNames)
{
    this.CodesNames = CodesNames;
}
```

How can I display this without the brackets?

Comment: The code you display is actually the setter, not the getter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get the brackets because `ArrayList#toString()` is implicitly called, in order to turn the list into a printable string. You can fix this by printing the list yourself in the JSP:

```xml
<c:forEach items="${CodesNames}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    ${item}<c:if test="${!status.last}">,</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

or with a bean getter than returns a string:

```
public String getCodesNamesAsString()
{
    // using a Guava Joiner
    return Joiner.on(",").useForNull("null").join(getCodesNames());
}
```

(See the [`Joiner` JavaDocs](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) if you're not familiar with Guava.)

Comment: Iterating through on the jsp was quick and fast...thanks man!!

Answer (score 2):

Add another getter method:

```
public void getCodesNamesFormatted()
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (String codeName : CodesNames) sb.append(codeName).append(',');
  return sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length());
}
```

And call it from JSP:

```
<td>${bean.codesNamesFormatted}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate it. Don't rely on `toString`.

```
<td>
    <c:forEach var="name" varStatus="stat" items="${bean.codesNames}">
        <c:out value="${name}"/>
        <c:if test="${stat.index < fn:length(bean.codesNames) - 1}">
            <c:out value=","/>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</td>
```

PS: The `<c:out/>` is optional here.

Comment: You don't need `<c:out/>` just for a comma.

Comment: Yes, I know. Just added it for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement getter which makes formatting you need

```
public String getCodesNamesFormatted()
{
    // format as you like
}
```

Then use it

```
<td>${bean.codesNamesFormatted}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

This string ([MCA, MCB, COMM, DMISA]) is generated by method toString() of class Array.
You need to create own code which will iterate over array elements and print them one-by-one.
Or of course you can use dirty way of replaceAll. See code below for both ways:

1)

```
<% for( String arrayItem : myArray ) { %>
<%= arrayItem %>,
<%}%>
```

2)

```
<%=myArray.toString().replaceAll("\[|\]","")%>
```

Comment: thanks for the input bro...I wish I could use scriptlets at this job...lol

Comment: Don't use scriptlets if you don't absolutely have to. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files